# costmap_2d python interface?

Tags: ros, navigation, rospy, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does it exist?  Or is there a way to have a running costmap_2d instance, but interact with it primarily through standard ros interfaces so that python could be used on the one end at least?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/185588/costmap_2d-python-interface?/) by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8729 on 2014-07-08

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Short answer: no.

Longer answer: [Previous question about navigation+python](http://answers.ros.org/question/174067/possible-to-write-move_base-plugin-in-python)

Follow up: what are you trying to do?

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2014-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2014-07-10**:
Follow up answer in the form of an answer, which is legitimate because it also answers my own question sort of.